# When using a nginx reverse proxy and webserver, what (http) setting goes where?

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy

The original webserver was set up with the `http` block below:

```
http {

    access_log off;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    client_body_timeout 10s;
    client_header_buffer_size 4k;
    client_header_timeout 10s;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types application/font-woff application/font-woff2 application/javascript application/json application/rss+$
    gzip_vary on;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    keepalive_timeout 60s;
    open_file_cache max=10240 inactive=60s;
    open_file_cache_errors on;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_valid 60s;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    send_timeout 10s;
    sendfile on;
    server_tokens off;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    tcp_nopush on;

}
```

Later, a reverse proxy was added and set up with the same `http` block as the webserver. Alltough working fine, I'm not sure what `http` settings are now redundant on the webserver and vice versa.

For example, gzip doesn't seem necessary on both...

And what about these (needed on reverse-proxy or webserver?):

```
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

Or these:

```
open_file_cache max=10240 inactive=60s;
open_file_cache_errors on;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_valid 60s;
sendfile on;
```

I'm not sure how to configure them properly together and couldn't find any docs on this specific matter.

Any insight? :-)

Update:

Reverse proxy:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {

        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.2:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    }

}
```

Webserver:

```
server {

    index index.php;
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/sites/example.com/;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        include /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to presume what you've written is exactly what you have. Apologies if that means my answer comes off as patronizing or pedantic.

The idea behind a reverse proxy is that it should work like a normal webserver, but when it receives requests from the outside world, it supplies pages pulled from some other webserver instead. It's a little unclear which of the two configurations you've provided here— is it the webserver with content, or is it the reverse proxy?

If you've supplied your nginx configuration in full, then the first problem in either case is that you're not actually serving anything. You're missing the fundamental `server` statement and won't return anything, to anyone. I'd be surprised to discover it even starts.

What you want to have is something like this (minimally speaking— a location statement isn't strictly necessary, but is more illustrative):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /path/to/your/files;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
  }
}
```

On the reverse proxy server's side, *as part of* the `server` block you *must* include a `location` statement with the [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) element (as documented in the link). This controls which requests to the reverse proxy will be *forwarded* to the normal webserver listening on the other side.

For the interaction of different settings, there's little guidance because you simply have to know what's going on, and decide for yourself whether it's redundant or not— in many cases this will be entirely dependent upon your design choices. However,  SAMEORIGIN as a header on the content webserver will *break* your setup, [unless you specifically pass the IP address of the requestor from the reverse proxy to the content webserver](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html). `gzip on;` may be redundant in some contexts, but this likely won't be the case if your reverse proxy pre-caches some pages.

I'm afraid there's no easy guide. You simply need to have a clearer plan for what you want to do, and then design accordingly. Just remember that the `http` block on the reverse proxy will control traffic to and from the outside world, whereas the `http` block on your content webserver will control traffic to and from *your reverse proxy*.

Comment: Only the http block I was a bit unsure about, but I’ve updated the original question with the missing blocks for both the reverse proxy and webserver. So far I’ve kept the gzip config on the proxy because it seems more logical there (I want content from the proxy to the client to be gzipped) and open_file_cache config on the webserver (the one actually handling the files). But to be honest settings were a lot clearer (to me) when it was just the webserver I had to deal with. Anyways, you gave me some good pointers, thank you :-)

Comment: @Viraldope your welcome. I'd also suggest making use of the pre-server parameter block `upstream mysite { server 192.168.0.2:80; }`, and then switching to use `proxy_pass mysite;`. It offers a bit more flexibility and clarity for managing all this, and makes it clearer for more complicated setups— you can have fallback addresses and other fun stuff in there.

Comment: I see in the question , that  ip&port ("listen" & "server_name") is the same in both proxy and web server, so how does nginx knows when to act as proxy and when as web server ?